# Copy to clipboard from IPython using Windows 7

Tags: windows, ipython, ipython-magic

I am running IPython on Windows 7 and can use the `%paste` magic command to paste from the clipboard. However, I cannot copy from IPython to the clipboard. I want to copy code snippets from IPython and paste them back to a text editor.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: I've never used ipython on windows, but if it works like a standard terminal window there is a menu item for selecting which puts you into select mode.  You can also change the properties to make selecting work in a more sane way.

Answer (score 7):

Found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nova77/5403446) to add a %copy magic command, [my fork](https://gist.github.com/asfaltboy/2dbe297ccab11c463884) adds supports osx/linux/windows platforms.

I have yet to test it on windows, so please tell me if you encounter any issues.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @AdrianRatnapala, you can right-click in the terminal window and select `Mark`, mark the code snippets you want to copy, and then right-click (the marked content is copied to the clipboard when you right-click).

A more "permanent way" to use this feature is to right-click on the title bar of the terminal window and choose `Properties`. Under the `Options` tab, tick the box next to `QuickEdit Mode` and save this setting.

A third option is to use [IPython's Qt Console](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html). You can use this by entering `ipython qtconsole` in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

A real permanent mode is to do what [sodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2022086/sodd) has told, but a little bit different:

Right click in the top of the shell window, but use `default` instead `properties` option, also select `options` and `Quick edit mode`.  Now this setting will survive in the next shell activations.

So it's very easy to copy and paste

Drag and drop to draw a rectangle inside shell screen and press `Enter`. The content is is in Clipboard. After, if you can paste this in the shell it's just press `Right` key or outside, use the usual `Ctrl+V`.

The cool thing is that you can now omit the number of commands in the copy.

[image]