# Converting ipython to python without line numbers commented

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

The command with nbconvert i.e: 
   `$ jupyter nbconvert --to script [YOUR_NOTEBOOK].ipynb`
converts ipython to .py file but my python file output is something like this:

```
# In[1]:

  import pandas as pd

# In[2]:
  data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
  d2  = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
```

I don't want the In[1]or In[2] lines at all. Is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47281997/2174832). The save magic command [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-save) saves the input lines you want to a file; the -a option is for "append" mode so that the lines are added at the end of the file instead of overwriting the file.

Just type

```
%save -a myipythonsession.py 1-100
```

`1-100` represent the line numbers that you want to save (you don't have to actually have 100 lines you can also have less in your session) 
`-a` will ensure that if the file that you save to already exists will not be overwritten, the lines that you save will be appended instead.