# Copy the output of `print` to clipboard directly

Tags: python, ipython

I use `inspect.getsource` to check the libs I imported:

```
In[52]: from django.views.generic import View
In[53]: view_code = inspect.getsource(View)
In[54]: len(view_code)
Out[54]: 3242
```

Retrieve the formatted codes

```
In[55]: print(view_code)

class View(object):
    """
    Intentionally simple parent class for all views. Only implements
    dispatch-by-method and simple sanity checking.
    """

    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put',
                        'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

I'd like to store the codes to my notes for further reference,
to do this, I have to scroll through the entire code with the purpose to copy it.
It's not convenient if the codes are long enough.

How could I copy the output of `print` to clipboard in a straight-forward way?

Comment: Do you actually want a way to capture the result of `print` to the clipboard, or just a way to send the string to the clipboard without printing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't have clipboard APIs built in, except as part of the `tkinter` GUI, but there are a number of libraries on PyPI that do.

For example, with [`pyperclip`](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip), you can copy any string you want to the clipboard like this:

```
In[56]: import pyperclip
In[57]: pyperclip.copy(view_code)
```

---

But you may be able to use `tkinter`. Depending on your platform, whether you're using a console-mode or qtconsole session, etc., this may not work, or may require popping up an unwanted window, but you can try it and see:

```
In [119]: import tkinter
In [120]: tk = tkinter.Tk()
In [121]: tk.clipboard_clear()
In [122]: tk.clipboard_append(view_code)
```

If your setup *does* require you to display a window (e.g., I think this will happen in a console-mode session on Windows), you might still be able to do it without too much distraction. See [this answer, suggested by J.Doe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4203897/908494) if you're interested.

---

But it might be simpler and more useful to just write to a file:

```
In[58}: with open('spam.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(view_code)
```

---

Or, since you're using IPython, you can use `%save` or various other magic commands. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070403/) so I don't have to go over them all here.)

---

Or, there are multiple third-party implementations of IPython addons to give you clipboard copy commands, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/asfaltboy/2dbe297ccab11c463884) (which I just found in a random search, so I'm not endorsing it or anything… but it seems to work):

```
In[61]: %clip view_code
```

---

If you actually need to capture the output of `print` for some reason, the two obvious ways to do it are to monkeypatch or shadow `print`, or to patch `sys.stdout`. For example:

```
import builtins
import io
import sys
def print(*args, **kw):
    if kw.get('file', sys.stdout) is sys.stdout:
        buf = io.StringIO()
        builtins.print(*args, **kw, file=buf)
        pyperclip.copy(buf.getvalue())
    builtins.print(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: Actually, there is the Tkinter.Tk clipboard methods.

Comment: @J.Doe Good point. Presumably the OP is in a console-mode or qtconsole session, and using tkinter may, depending on the platform, either not work, or require popping up an unwanted window… but it will work in at least some cases; I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @J.Doe I already added one to the answer, but I'll link to that one for more detail.

Comment: May want to mention the `tkinter`/`Tkinter` backwards incompatibility

Comment: @J.Doe I don't think it's necessary to mention Python 2 in questions about Python 3 in 2018.

Comment: He technically didn't mention Python 3

Comment: @J.Doe Also, if you really need to use Python 2.x, you have to deal with the way Tkinter mishandles Unicode until somewhere around 2.7.9, and the way it still mishandles astral characters after that. Not to mention that the whole `print` thing doesn't work, or even make sense, without a `__future__` declaration…

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173184/discussion-between-j-doe-and-abarnert).